# Не срабатывает проверка наличия елемента в JsonArray android

Tags: android, json, recyclerview.adapter

Пытаюсь сделать прикрепление файлов к письму. Сейчас получается выбрать файл из проводника и отправить в массив. Дальше я отображаю прикрепленные файлы в списке. В чем проблема - я могу прикрепить два одинаковых файла, а иногда и больше 5. Не могу понять в чем проблема. В итоге я сделал проверку, но она не срабатывает так как нужно. Вот мои шаги для прикрепления файла:

1. Выбрать файл через адаптер:

   ```
   fileManager.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

           if (file.isDirectory()) {

               ((WriteResponseMess) ctx).recreateRecyclerView(file.getPath());
           } else {
               if (getFolderSize(file) > 20) {
                   ((WriteResponseMess) ctx).convertFileToString(file.getPath());
               } else {
                   Log.i("m", ">20");
               }

           }

       });
   ```

   В адаптере я проверяю является ли выбранный елемент списка файлом или папкой и если это файл то мы переходим к шагу 2.
2. Кодируем файл:

   ```
   public void convertFileToString(String pathOnSdCard) {
       dialog.dismiss();

       File file = new File(pathOnSdCard);
       if (ms.getArray() != null) {
           if (ms.getArray().size() > 0) {
               for (int i = 0; i < ms.getArray().size(); i++) {
                   JsonObject object = ms.getArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                   String nFile = object.get("filename").getAsString();

                   Log.i("m", nFile + "\n" + object.get("filename"));

                   if (!file.getName().equals(nFile)) {
                       try {
                           byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
                           uploadFiles(ms.getArray(), new File(pathOnSdCard).getName(), Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));

                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(this, "You have already attached this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }
           } else {
               try {
                   byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array
                   uploadFiles(ms.getArray(), new File(pathOnSdCard).getName(), Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }


       }
   }
   ```

в этой функции я проверяю есть ли уже в массиве елементы, если есть то проверяю есть ли такой файл уже в массиве, и именно эта проверка у меня не срабатывает почему-то правильно. Получается если я выбираю такой же файл второй раз то у меня выводится тост что файл уже выбран один раз, и все-равно файл прикрепляется. Чувствую что проблема где-то в цикле но не смог найти где именно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле нужно только проверить есть ли элемент в массиве. А добавлять уже после цикла, если дубликат не найден.

```
public void convertFileToString(String pathOnSdCard) {
    dialog.dismiss();

    File file = new File(pathOnSdCard);
    JsonArray array = ms.getArray();
    if (array == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        String nFile = object.get("filename").getAsString();

        Log.i("m", nFile + "\n" + object.get("filename"));

        if (file.getName().equals(nFile)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have already attached this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    }
    try {
        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array
        uploadFiles(array, file.getName(), Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: есть небольшая проблема с предложенным вами вариантом решения, вот ситуация - прикрепили один файл, все нормально, прикрепили второй файл, тоже все хорошо, прикрепляем третий файл - в итоге прикрепилось 2 файла, прикрепляем четвертый файл - прикрепилось 4 файла, что-то не так работает наверное :(

Comment: В этом куске кода я не вижу никаких проблем. Он работает как и задумано: если файла нет, то последний блок выполнится, если есть - покажет тост и выйдет из метода. Ищите причину дальше.

Comment: вы мне подали идею как усовершенствовать свой метод по загрузке в массив и это похоже сработало, спасибо большое за помощь :)